# nested State sync failed trying to build a dynamic list component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was trying to develop a dynamic list component, which involves state snyc. I have to admit the current design is terrible, it's not readable but at least I've made some progress. However I can't solve an issue, the delete has a bug.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wkqoz0wwv8

To reproduce it:

1. click 'add more' twice, to add 2 new item.
2. fill in the value for the last dropdown.
3. delete the 2nd list.

Something is not right there, it supposes to delete the 2nd item and kep the state of the last item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not how you are removing the state but how you are rendering it, you are actually using the times function to creates a loop will will iterate `row_count` number of times and give you the index,

All you need to do is iterate over your data object like

```
return (
  <div className="companyContactInfo-addContact">
    {Object.keys(company_contacts).map(i => this.singleContact(i))}

    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-xs-12">
        <a onClick={::this.addNewRow}>
          <span>Add</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Also you once the duplicated variable is modified you could just assign it to state rather than using spread operator

```
  handleInputChange(e, index) {
    let targetedContact = this.state.company_contacts[index];
    targetedContact.value = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      company_contacts: {
        ...this.state.company_contacts,
        [index]: targetedContact
      }
    });
  }
```

**[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2144mw6ry)**

Comment: I have modified your sandbox a little considering the other changes like using `prevState` syntax for setState and cloning state before making changes,

Comment: is row_count needed in my case?

Comment: No it isn't, you can just get away with it

Comment: I'm not sure how did I came up with a crappy design in the first place, actually I was doing trial and error to make this work, for you what will be the first step you would do?

Comment: I would rather have an array of objects, rather than nested objects. I could actually clean up the sandbox for you

Comment: Check this edited sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/342662644m with the modified logic

Comment: you're right, object pair worked but it's kinda messy, better use array here. Thanks so much for the rewrite!